# Validation error while using Llama2Chat with ChatOpenAI LLM in langchain

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, llama

I have a llama 2 model hosted using vLLM. Calling the endpoint with langchain `ChatOpenAI` works fine. I am trying to use `Llama2Chat` as a wrapper, from `langchain_experimental` for prompt curation. But I am getting the following validation error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Llama2Chat
llm
  Can't instantiate abstract class LLM with abstract methods _call, _llm_type (type=type_error)
```

Here is the simple code to reproduce:

```py
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_experimental.chat_models import Llama2Chat


chat_llm = ChatOpenAI(openai_api_base="vllm-endpoint")
model = Llama2Chat(llm=chat_llm)
```

Any help is appreciated.